# After publishing to IIS 7, Web Api 2 Post method generates Internal Server Error? What shall I do?

Tags: asp.net, post, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In my ASP.NET web project, I have an api controller, in that there is a post method like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/token")]
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult CustomToken ([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
    {
        .....
        return Ok("success");
    }

}
```

Now in Visual Studio, this api controller works fine, returns "success" with 200 status code, but when I publish it to IIS, this creates 500 Internal Server Exception. I have used logging here, and no exception is created in the whole code inside the POST method.

Update: In the API project StartUp file, I used the following configuration:

```
private void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.EnableCors();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    var jsonFormatter = 
            config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();

   jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver 
            = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

Comment: Check server event viewer for any exceptions causing 500 server error. Also, how are you generating custom token based on UserDTo as the code may be failing on the server

Comment: Dear Mohsin, Token generation is not failing on the server. I have logging in there, and we are getting token from logging. Kind of stuck.

Comment: Any exception logged in event viewer?

Comment: Sorry Mohsin, just 500 exception logged. No details.

Comment: Weird! Are you saying 500 exception is logged in `Windows Eventviewer` or under your custom logger? Also, you can check IIS logs which are located at `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) or your browser's built in debugging tools (F12) to inspect the traffic when you make the API call.
ASP.Net Web API should return a **Post Response** back in HTML form with an Exception message.  If it doesn't return a proper meaningful error message then you may have `<customErrors mode="on">` in your web.config file.  This should be set to `off` while you are trying to debug the issue.

Comment: Check the Response (like the HTML that is returned) there may be an Exception listed in there

Comment: @DebKantiBarua, Is there no Response when the 500 error returns?

Comment: There is no response, just 500 error. I put a try/catch in the method, and the code is not reaching the catch block.

Comment: I am also putting customErrors mode="off">, but no error is popping off.